# Comprehensive CEP (Proton) REST API documentation

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing

I've searched the repo + FiWare Wikis and was unable to find any detailed API documentation.

I saw this: http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Complex_Event_Processing_Open_RESTful_API_Specification

I'm running a CEP instance on Fiware Cloud, and keep getting 500's and 405's for the calls I'm trying.
Yet it often references the user guide for more details on each endpoint parameter. Is there a more recent version?

Last release was more than a year ago, according to that spec. Are the docs up to date with the latest API version?

Else I'll have to reverse-engineer the API...

PS: CEP instance is running @ http://130.206.117.120:8080/ 
    Let me know if there are some sanity checks I can make ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using CEP and for REST API I haven't found newer specs (from the doc you linked). However, I didn't have any problems getting the resources.

You can try 
`GET: http://130.206.117.120:8080/ProtonOnWebServerAdmin/resources/instances/ProtonOnWebServer`

It shows state and definitions-url of the engine.

I found it helpful to browse through examples from engine also, or from [tuts](https://edu.fiware.org/course/view.php?id=58).

I saw that your instance uses DoSAttack definition and I have tried POSTing to engine: `POST: http://130.206.117.120:8080/ProtonOnWebServer/rest/events, header: Content-Type: application/json, payload: {"Name":"TrafficReport","volume":"22"}` and got `200 OK`.

For more complex tasks (apart from REST API) this [PAGE](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/CEP_GE_-_Proactive_Technology_Online_User_and_Programmer_Guide) lists latest specs.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks. I got this response from the CEP dev team: "First of all, we are currently working on extending the documentation for the RESTful API of Proton, but currently - the wiki entry you attached is the documentation we have.
Furthermore, we made some restructuring to the whole project about a week ago, and so redownloading it and running the new files should solve this problem."